# Rename [timezoneoffset] to [timezone-offset]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

To improve readability, I would like to propose renaming [timezoneoffset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/timezoneoffset) to [timezone-offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/timezone-offset).

This would keep naming consistency with the main [timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/timezone) tag, while also making the tag easier to read at a glance.